# Efficient formulations for reservoir constraints in CP solvers

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming

I am fairly new to constraint programming, so apologies for any misconceptions.

Assume the following example problem:

A pump is moving water from a bottomless lake into a tightly constrained reservoir at a set rate. There is demand on the reservoir over the day with each hour having different demand. The goal is to ensure the reservoir stays within limits by turning the pump on and off.

Example data for a 6hr problem:

```
res_bounds = [0, 20]
demand = [0,8,1,13,11,12]
```

A feasible solution would be:

```
pump_schedule = [1,1,0,1,1,1]
```

Giving a volume profile of

```
[10,12,11,8,7,5]
```

When modelling the above example with a MIP, the "standard" formulation is discretized 1-hour steps with an underlying mass-balance model. These models, however, tend to scale poorly when the time steps become too fine or the size of the problem gets out of hand.

At first glance, CP offers a solution with features such as interval variables for efficiently scheduling the pump at a very fine resolution. However, tracking the reservoir levels proves a challenge as the model has no visibility of the levels in the middle of the pump running interval.

Google's or-tools offers [AddReservoirConstraintWithActive](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model?hl=en#addreservoirconstraintwithactive) to model the problem exactly as I described it, but seems to require discrete boolean time variables, running into the same issue as the MIP solvers.

In short, is there a way in constraint programming to model such reservoir constraints without boolean time variables? I tried looking around online but found nothing that would help so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reservoir constraint asks for integer time variables, not Boolean variables. It does not discretize time.

Comment: Does that still work if the "demands" are dependent on the run length of the pump (in this case)? From the reference doc:
**"then the current level changes by demands[i], which is constant,"**

Comment: Also, I guess I interpreted the boolean "active" variables as something that can be used to discretize time - I suppose they are not really meant for that.